# Extract relevant features from time series data

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, regression, linear-regression

I have a time series data set from a sensor and the task is to predict the time before a failure event is occurred. The data set has one feature, no date or timestamp and has almost 20 million rows. This is a regression problem.

I tried polynomial features, auto correlation, rolling statistics and expanding statistics. The only one that seemed to improve my model was expanding sum. What are some relevant features to be extracted from this data?

My model is a Linear Regression model, the data set was scaled and currently only two features improved my model. The sensor data and the expanding sum. Any other suggestions to tackle this problem other than using deep learning?

Update: For clarification I added the plots for both the input and output.

Sensor reading plot - Input
[image: Sensor reading input]

Time to failure plot - Output
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the data using the various feature transformations you listed?

Comment: What is the sensor, measurement and failure mode in the dataset?

Comment: Also, it looks like your failures occur almost always at the same time. Why not just use time as the feature to predict based on?

Comment: I didn't look at the data when using feature transformations. No other information is provided with the dataset other than the reading of such sensor and time it takes for failure for each reading so I was not able to include time.